# Object #<Object> has no method 'apply' when using Observable directly

Tags: knockout.js

I have a plunk that shows an issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/VcLSX8KmyPwxU6EXe9RR.

If you select a row, a modal will appear.  If you click the cancel button another modal will appear to confirm the cancel.  On the cancel modal, there are two "No" buttons.  One updates an observable directly and the other updates the observable through another function.  Both appear to work as expected, but the one that calls the observable directly throws an error in the console.

I'm looking for some more information about this.  I didn't want to have an extra function exposed to update this observable, but if that's the correct way to do it then that's how I'll do it.  Also, if it is the correct way, is there some place that explains why it's the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `click` binding, you want to make sure that you are passing a reference to a function rather than invoking a function directly.

So, in your binding you are doing:

```
data-bind="click: $parent.showCancelDialog(false)"
```

This will end up executing your code while it is being bound. You would want to either point at a function that sets it to false like:

```
data-bind="click: $parent.hideCancelDialog"
```

with that function setting it to `false` or you could use `bind` to create a function inline with a fixed first argument like:

```
data-bind="click: $parent.showCancelDialog.bind(null, false)"
```

The first argument is the context (`this` when it is executed), which does not matter for setting an observable, which is why I just used `null`.

Comment: as an aside, here is how I like to do modals: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/UJh65/. This makes the `modal` binding work like the `with` or `template` bindings in KO.  Set an observable and the modal shows up using the value of the observable as its context. Clear the observable and the modal hides (or hide the modal and the observable is cleared for you). It makes using a modal very similar to using the `with` binding.